# Twitter Integration with Twitter 4j not working

Tags: android, twitter4j

I`ve just  updated my Twitter 4j Library from 2.2.4 to 3.0.3 i run the application and click to share but when i clicked 
twitter respond the following Page [image]

does any body have this issue before if so then how to solve it 
thank you in advance

Comment: Can you try connecting with an https link? This broke for me as well. You aren't supposed to be using http urls for authenticating anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a lot of things:

- Connection problem;
- Temporary unreachable servers;
- Wrong/invalid/expired OAuth token

First try again later, then give a look at the settings page of your twitter page.
I use these URLs in my app:

```
public static final String REQUEST_URL = "http://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token";
public static final String ACCESS_URL = "http://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token";
public static final String AUTHORIZE_URL = "http://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize";
```

Try some log and debugging, maybe you can find the error directly from the code.